# 777 permission is not getting set for jar file

Tags: java, linux, filesystems

I am copying few jar files from linux machine to Linux machine using java code, while copying I am setting 777 permission to all jars, but if I go and see jars in copied location, permission is not being set. What might be the issue? Can anyone help

```
file.setExecute(true);
file.setReadable(true);
file.setWritable(true):
```

Comment: How are Windows and Linux filesystems connected ? Samba ?

Comment: @ygor My bad both are Linux , I am copying from one location to other in linux

Comment: Still, is it a single Linux machine ? Or two Linux machines? How is the target directory mounted?

Comment: Single Linux machine, Hadoop directory

Comment: Copying from.one Hadoop directly to other in same Linux machine

Answer (score 2):

First of all, what you are doing is not equivalent to setting the permissions to `0777`.

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#setExecutable(boolean)) for `java.io.File::setExecutable` states:

> A convenience method to set **the owner's** execute permission for this abstract pathname.

Note that it doesn't say what the call does to the "group" and "other" permissions.

Secondly, you are not checking the return values from the calls, so they may be silently failing ... as would typically happen on Linux if the application's effective uid wasn't the file owner, or root.

For Java 7 and later, a better way to do this would be to use `java.nio.file.Files::setPosixFilePermissions` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#setPosixFilePermissions(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.util.Set)))

- It allows you more control over the permission set
- It throws exceptions if the operation doesn't work.